# socket not bind() ing - Invalid argument

Tags: c, linux

Good evening to all,
  For kicks and giggles I'm trying my hand at *NIX sockets and TCP/IP.  Now, to get off the ground I'm simply trying to create a socket on two endpoints and a basic text chat program back and forth.  Now, before I'm even up and running I'm hit with a bind 'Invalid Argument':

```
user@user-VirtualBox:~/sockets$ ./socket
sock=3
s_->sin_family = 2
s_->sin_port = 3879
s_->sin_addr.s_addr = 0
sockfd = 3
s_->sin_family = 2
s_->sin_port = 3879
s_->sin_addr.s_addr = 0
Socket bind error: Invalid argument
sizeof(s_) = 8
```

Code below.  so, INADDR_ANY should be 255.255.225.255 = 0, from what I understand; AF_INET is 2; and sin_port, well, I've looked at the binary backward and forward and am not sure I understand how 9000 is represented in host order at 3879 from 9000, but assume it's a non-issue. Additionally, since 1 is stdout and 2 is stderr, I assume that anything above this is dynamically allocated and so 3 should be fine for the socket file descriptor.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
void setSocket(struct sockaddr_in* s_){
    s_->sin_family=AF_INET;
    s_->sin_port=htons(9999);
    s_->sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
    memset(&(s_->sin_zero), '\0', 8);
    printf("s_->sin_family = %i\n", s_->sin_family);    
    printf("s_->sin_port = %i\n", s_->sin_port);
    printf("s_->sin_addr.s_addr= %i\n", s_->sin_addr.s_addr);
}

void createSocket(int *sock){
    if ((*sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Socket creation error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("sock = %i\n", *sock);
    fflush(stdout);
}

void bindSocket(int sock, struct sockaddr_in* s_){
    printf("s_->sin_family = %i\n",s_->sin_family);
    printf("s_->sin_port = %i\n",s_->sin_port);
    printf("s_->sin_addr.s_addr = %i\n",s_->sin_addr.s_addr);
    if((bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)s_, (socklen_t)sizeof(s_))) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Socket bind error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
    printf("sizeof(s_) = %lu\n", sizeof(s_));
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in socket_;
    createSocket(&sockfd);
    setSocket(&socket_);
    printf("sockfd = %i\n", sockfd);
    fflush(stdout);
    bindSocket(sockfd, &socket_);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Try replacing it with `if((bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)s_, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))) == -1){`. Also, there really is no need to cast the size to socklen_t.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is the

> sizeof()
>   inside your bind()... 's_' is a pointer, so its sizeof is (probably) 4...
>   You need to dereference it:

```
if((bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)s_, (socklen_t)sizeof(*s_))) == -1){
    fprintf(stderr, "Socket bind error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
```

Comment: This makes sense to me, BUT when I change this it throws a ton of errors when attempting to compile via gcc.  I can post them but they're quite a handful and 'too long by 4950 characters'; let me know if this would be best served in a new question.

Comment: When I compile with gcc on ubuntu 14.04LTS, I get only the following warning: sock.c: In function ‘bindSocket’:
sock.c:33:5: warning: format ‘%lu’ expects argument of type ‘long unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("sizeof(s_) = %lu\n", sizeof(s_));
     ^
The only change I made to the code you posted was the addition of the asterisk (*).

Comment: Yes, that's the same setup I have.  I'll play with this new problem some,  but I imagine that the original complaint is now behind me.  Thank you!